# python use raw_input for range filenames

Tags: python, file, raw-input

Currently I've got a script that consumes text filename (for example 1.txt) from raw input, opens it and then parses it for my needs:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(str(fname))
...
```

There are 10 files in the directory: 1.txt, 2.txt, ... 10.txt

So how can I input range filenames in raw input like from 2.txt to 6.txt and parse these files 1 by 1. Instead of running script every time for a single file?

Comment: it's all upto you. you can do something like `foobar(filename='test',range=[1,9],ext='txt')`

Comment: And what approach did you try so far?

Comment: don't you hear of loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that the file names are `n.tx`t where `n >= 1`
then,

```
def parse(flie):
    pass
    # this is where you parse the file.

lower = raw_input("Enter start: ") # assume int
upper = raw_input("Enter end: ") # assume int and >= lower
files = [str(i)+'.txt' for i in range(int(lower),int(upper)+1)]

for file in files:
    parse(file)
```